# RMySQL update row, not full table

Tags: mysql, r, database, rmysql

Does anyone know how I can use `RMySQL` (or another library) to update a row in a table, rather than having to pull out the full table and push it back in? I don't want to read such a huge table into memory just to update one row.

What I am trying to do is pull out a row, change some of the values in there within R and push the same row object back into the table.

However, `dbWriteTable` seems to replace the entire table rather than just the row I specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to construct a string within R containing the adequate [SQL Update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement and use `dbSendQuery` to push your data back into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Using **sqldf** package:

```
library(sqldf)
table_name = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 4)
# Open connection
sqldf()
fn$sqldf("update table_name set b=1")
ans = sqldf("select * from main.table_name")
# Close connection
sqldf()
print(table_name)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you've done here. Can you break it down? What kind of object is is fn?

Comment: In general we must use the fn$ prefix to invoke the interpolation functionality. i.e. We can pass the R- objects or variables into the sql query. `fn$sqldf("update table_name set b=$var")` Where var = 1 in the above code